# How to send Allure Reports in Email using Jenkins server

Tags: allure

I have created a Automation using Rest Assured, TestNg, Gradle and Allure reports. Now i am able to generate Allure reports , But i am looking something where i can send Allure reports in Email. Whether this is any plugin is available or any latest deployment is going on

Comment: Were you able to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** you need to install Email Extension plugin in your Jenkins. You can also use the default Jenkins mail but I prefer the Email Extension plugin since it's more configurable.

**Second** you need smtp server to send email from Jenkins. If you have one then cool otherwise create one. (If you are using gmail then your smtp server is smtp.gmail.com by default)

**Third** is you need to configure Jenkins. Open your Jenkins Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Configure Systems. Then scroll down to Email Extension. If you have decided to use the default Email the scroll down to Email and enter the details and save.

[image]

**Fourth** you need to add the following code to your existing pipeline.

```
 stage('Email Report') {
    // Change the recipent address
    sh "zip -r allure-report.zip allure-report"
    def mailRecipients = "therecipient@mail.com"
    env.ForEmailPlugin = env.WORKSPACE
    if(fileExists('allure-report.zip')){
        emailext(
            to: "${mailRecipients}",
            from: "sender@mail.com",
            subject: "Allure Report",
            body: "PFA",
            attachmentsPattern: 'allure-report.zip'
        )
    } else{
        echo("COULD NOT FIND FILE TO ATTACH")
        }
}
```

**Fifth** the recipient need to download the zip attachment and execute `allure serve` to see the reports and dashboards.

**It's worth noting that the best way to serve allure report is to upload in some common place for example in jira, confluence etc.**